# Secure spring webapp with cookies

Tags: spring, security, cookies, web

I am writing a little service which uses websockets (not topic!). I researched on how to secure websockets. But the documentations all say I have to secure the webapp like every other webapp (i.e. basic auth). I already tried basic auth and it seems to work. But I am in the need of securing the websocket service by cookies. So my question is:

How do you secure a spring webapp by cookies?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done via servlet filters.

```
@Service
public class MyCookieAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    //set principal to request after request was validated...
  }
}
```

You have to register the filter too.